# Custom signals in Python

Tags: python, django, signals

I read the Django documentations about making my own signals but it is quiet difficult for me to grasp. Can you give me an example of making your own signal and  give some details please?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create custom signal by defining

```
from django.dispatch import Signal


content_object_state_change = Signal(providing_args=["content_object", "created"])
```

Then you can send by it like below:

```
content_object_state_change.send(
    sender=sender or obj.__class__, content_object=obj, created=True
)
```

And receive it as below. genrally this code can go to `app.ready.py` function which get register when app initiate:

```
content_object_state_change.connect(content_object_state_change_receiver)
```

`content_object_state_change_receiver` is a function with logic you would like to implement.

Comment: Thank you, 
I can't understand good enough unless there is an exmaple. Can you please help me understand the pizza example stated in Django documentation 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#defining-signals

Comment: Sure,`pizza_done` is custom signal created first to use in the Django app and then you have to send it by which on URL done by `send_pizza` function and then you have register function to receive it. you can do it by what I have mentioned earlier or using decorator `@receiver` to function